# Convert dart code into html/JS web format

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to convert pure Flutter/Dart code into Html and JS?
My aim is to a basic webpage but from a widget I have created in Flutter. I have read that Dart is compiled behind with JS .
Just wondering if I would be able to see the code behind a page created in flutter, like this one:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardWebQR extends class name extends StatelessWidget {
  const name({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("QR Code"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.76,
              child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  elevation: 10,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('hello'),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Text('bye'),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 30,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}
```